# Celery Task.AsyncResult takes task_id but is documented to "Get AsyncResult instance for this kind of task" - Why?

Tags: celery

I'm a little confused by this. The [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html) for `Task.AsyncResult` states clearly that it will:

> Get AsyncResult instance for this kind of task.

yet the [signature](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.AsyncResult) for this method clearly takes a task_id described as:

> Arguments:
>               task_id (str): Task id to get result for.

Now am I just a little too pedantic or failing to understand how a "kind of task" is described by a `"task_id"`. Am I simply overthinking this or under-understanding it?

I imagine `task_id` is the `UUID` of an already running task?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, `task_id` doesn't describe a "kind of task", saying "kind of task" I believe it refers to any async Celery task ran with `delay` or `apply_async`.

Comment: If I read you right, we'd be agreed that the comment and documentation should be amended to "Get AsyncResult for a specified task.". If we are right in that my confusion around this documentation is abated.

Comment: Yes, I would, even though there are other kinds of _Result_ (`EagerResult`, `GroupResult`), I'm not aware of any other kind of _Task_ for which `AsyncResult` wouldn't work. Your description sounds better to me.

Comment: OK, submitted a PR here:

https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/5900